# need to insert from grid to mysql database

Tags: mysql, triggers, grid, processmaker

I want to insert the data I have in my grid in table 'quote' in my database, when I put this code in the trigger on ProcessMaker.
when I tried with a normal form it worked but if the grid it works I think it's a problem of syntax or foreach gridsizerows n is not, can someone please help me:
here is the code

```php
$i=0 foreach ($i < $gridsizerows) {
   $i = i +1;
   $id = @mygrid [$i]['id'];
   $quantity = @mygrid[$i]['quantity'];
   $pu = @mygrid[$i]['possible'];
   $pt = @mygrid[$i]['pt'];
   $to = @mygrid [$i]['designation'];
   $sql = "INSERT INTO quotes (id, designation, quantity, pu, pt) VALUES ($id, $from, $pu, $pt, $amount)";
   $tmp_db = executeQuery($sql, '90911865253a802b030e577077431812');
}
```

Comment: }//////   $i=0
foreach ($ i <$ gridsizerows)
{
$ $ i = i +1;
$ id = @ @ mygrid [$ i] ['id'];
$ quantity = @ @ mygrid [$ i] ['quantity'];
$ pu = @ @ mygrid [$ i] ['possible'];
$ pt = @ @ mygrid [$ i] ['pt'];
$ to = @ @ mygrid [$ i] ['designation'];

$ sql = "INSERT INTO quotes (id, designation, quantity, pu, pt) VALUES ('$ id', '$ from', '$ pu', '$ pt', '$ amount')";
$ tmp_db = executeQuery ($ sql, '90911865253a802b030e577077431812 ');  /////////

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good, 2 possible changes you might want to do are as given below..

Instead of this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO quotes (id, designation, quantity, pu, pt) VALUES ($id, $from, $pu, $pt, $amount)";
```

Use this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO quotes (id, designation, quantity, pu, pt) VALUES ('$id', '$from', '$pu', '$pt', '$amount')";
```

and Instead of this:

```
$tmp_db = executeQuery($sql, '90911865253a802b030e577077431812');
```

Use this:

```
$dbConn = '90911865253a802b030e577077431812';
$tmp_db = executeQuery($sql, $dbConn);
```